# I want to use a shell script to check the disk space and output the specified value, but it didn't work

Tags: shell

I am learning shell, I want to use shell script to check disk space and output value, but it doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=""
ALERT=40

OUT_FLAG() {
        local check_value=$1
        local result_value=$2
        if [ ${check_value} -eq 0 ];then
             result="$result|${result_value}:0"
        else
             result="$result|${result_value}:1"
        fi
}
Check_disk() {
        local disk_result=0
        df -Pl | grep -vE "^Filesystem|tmpfs|cdrom" | awk '{print $5 " " $6}'|while read output;
        do
                usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
                if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then
                disk_result=1
                fi
        done
        OUT_FLAG ${disk_result} "disk"

}
Check_disk
echo $result
```

I want it to output |disk:1 but it is |disk:0.
Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: The underlying problem here is described in detail in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Answer (score 0):

The `df -Pl | ... | while` pipeline runs as a subshell, and `disk_result` is only being set in the subshell.  After the `done`, `disk_result` retains the value it had outside the subshell.  There are some shells in which this is not true, but it is the case in `bash`. The simplest solution is to expand the scope with something like:

```
    df -Pl | ... | { while read output;
    do ...; done; 
    OUT_FLAG "${disk_result}" disk; 
    }
```

By putting the call to OUT_FLAG (Note that `OUT_FLAG` is a terrible name for a function) inside the braces, it becomes part of the subshell, so `disk_result` is defined as you expect.